# Change Line in text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have text document contains line name and next line its value.
I wrote this but I can't rewrite the line after replaced it.

```
public bool checkExist(string catName)
{
    int saveValue = 0;
    bool found = false;
    
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Form1.INCOMES_EXPENSE_VALUES_MONTH + Form1.CurrentMonth.ToString() + ".txt"/*get the file that I need to search in*/))
    {
        if (line == catName)
        {
            found = true;
            index++;
            continue;
        }
        else
            index++;

        if (found)
        {
            saveValue = int.Parse(line);
            saveValue += int.Parse(txtValue.Text);
            line.Replace(line, saveValue.ToString());
            
            found = false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: you need to write the file back to disk, you can look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file) for examples

Comment: @styx, if the input string is already exist in the file, the I need to add its value to the old one so I did it, and replace the line with the new value and it worked but I can't change the line in the file with the new value

Comment: why you cant change?

Comment: @styx, I'm sorry, I mean don't know how to change it in the file

Comment: if you are reading all lines anyway, u can truncate the file, and then write your new lines

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing a simple *Finite State Machine*; we have two states here: line before is `catName` (`found == true`) or not (`found == false`):

```
  private static IEnumerable<string> UpdatedCat(string file, string catName, int add) {
    bool found = false;  

    // AllLines: materialization if you want to write the modified data 
    // back to the same file
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file)) {
      if (found) {
        found = false;

        int value = int.Parse(line);

        yield return $"{value + add}";     
      }
      else {
        yield return line;  

        // Trim() : to be on the safe side if line has leading / trailing spaces
        found = (line.Trim() == catName);
      }
    } 
  }
```

Then you can put

```
  string file = $"{Form1.INCOMES_EXPENSE_VALUES_MONTH}{Form1.CurrentMonth}.txt";

  File.WriteAllLines(file, UpdatedCat(file, "MyCat", int.Parse(txtValue.Text)));
```

Comment: Just an off-topic suggestion: don't assume the OP is using latest C# compiler; you introduced **string interpolation** (that require C# 6) where the OP used `ToString` and a simple concatenation. You are indeed offering an insight into valuable technology that the OP could not be aware of, but at the same time the solution complexity is increasing due to additional differences from the original code sample.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can only modify a file (line) with write back the entire file (lines),
example:

`Read entire file lines` > `modify the line in temp` > `write back modified entire lines to file`

To **change line** in file

```
ChangeLine(@"This is modified line", @"C:\MyFile.txt", 6);
```

```
public void ChangeLine(string newText, string fullPath, int lineToEdit)
{
    // Read entire file lines
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath);

    // Edit the line
    lines[lineToEdit - 1] = newText;

    // Write back to file
    File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, lines, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

To **delete line** in file

```
DeleteLine(@"C:\MyFile.txt", 6);
```

```
public void DeleteLine(string fullPath, int lineToDelete)
{
    string line = null;
    int line_number = 0;
    var newstr = new StringBuilder();

    // Read entire file lines
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullPath))
    {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line_number++;
            // Exclude deleted line
            if (line_number == lineToDelete)
                continue;
            newstr.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }

    // Write back to file
    using (StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        sw.Write(newstr.ToString().TrimEnd()); // Remove blank line at end
    }
}
```

To **insert line** at line index in file

```
InsertLineAtIndex(@"C:\MyFile.txt", 6, @"This is new line");
```

```
public static void InsertLineAtIndex(
  string fullPath,
  int atIndex,
  string lineToAdd,
  bool toBelow = false)
{
    // Read entire file lines
    var txtLines = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath).ToList();

    // Specify insert location
    int index = toBelow ? (atIndex - 1) + 1 : (atIndex - 1);
    if (index > 0)
    {
        // Insert the line
        txtLines.Insert(index, lineToAdd);

        // Write back to file
        File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, txtLines, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

To **insert line** by known string in file

```
InsertLineByKnownString(@"C:\MyFile.txt", "Some string in my lines", @"This is new line ");
```

```
public void InsertLineByKnownString(
  string fullPath,
  string lineToSearch,
  string lineToAdd,
  bool toBelow = false)
{
    // Read entire file lines
    var txtLines = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath).ToList();

    // Specify insert location
    int index = toBelow ? txtLines.IndexOf(lineToSearch) + 1 : txtLines.IndexOf(lineToSearch);

    if (index > 0)
    {
        // Insert the line
        txtLines.Insert(index, lineToAdd);

        // Write back to file
        File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, txtLines, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```